# How to build a pandas dataframe (or dict) in an efficient way by selecting some lists of data from another bigger dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I need to create a DataFrame or dictionary. If `N = 3` (number of lists inside other list) the expected output is this:

```
d = {
    'xs0': [[7.0, 986.0], [17.0, 6.0], [7.0, 67.0]],
    'ys0': [[79.0, 69.0], [179.0, 169.0], [729.0, 69.0]],
    'xs1': [[17.0, 166.0], [17.0, 116.0], [17.0, 126.0]],
    'ys1': [[179.0, 169.0], [179.0, 1169.0], [1729.0, 169.0]],
    'xs2': [[27.0, 276.0], [27.0, 216.0], [27.0, 226.0]],
    'ys2': [[279.0, 269.0], [279.0, 2619.0], [2579.0, 2569.0]]
}
```

For this I have programmed the following code. But I need this code to run faster:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df_dict = {
    'X1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, np.nan],
    'Y1': [9, 29, 39, 49, np.nan, 69, 79, 89, 99],
    'X2': [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, np.nan],
    'Y2': [119, 129, 139, 149, np.nan, 169, 179, 189, 199],
    'X3': [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, np.nan],
    'Y3': [219, 229, 239, 249, np.nan, 269, 279, 289, 299],
    'S': [123, 11, 123, 11, 123, 123, 123, 35, 123],
    'C': [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
    'F': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
    'OTHER': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90],
}
bigger_df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)

plots = [
    { 'x': 'X1', 'y': 'Y1', },
    { 'x': 'X2', 'y': 'Y2', },
    { 'x': 'X3', 'y': 'Y3', }
]

N = 3
d = {}
s_list = [123, 145, 35]
n = 0
for p in plots:
    # INITIALIZATES THE DICTIONARY ELEMENTS
    d['xs{}'.format(n)] = [[] for x in range(N)]
    d['ys{}'.format(n)] = [[] for x in range(N)]        

    # BUILDS THE LISTS FOR THOSE ELEMENTS
    for index in range(3):
        df = bigger_df.filter([p['x'], p['y'], 'S', 'F', 'C'])        # selects the minimum of columns needed
        df = df[df['F'].isin([2, 3, 4, 9]) & df[p['x']].notnull() & df[p['y']].notnull() & (df.S == s_list[index])]
        df.sort_values(['C'], ascending=[True], inplace=True)

        d['xs{}'.format(n)][index] = list(df[p['x']])
        d['ys{}'.format(n)][index] = list(df[p['y']])
    n += 1
print(d)
```

I am wondering if instead of building the dictionary on a loop I could do some trick with pandas or numpy. If the result is a pandas dataframe rather than a dictionary is also good for me, or even better, but I do not if it will be more efficient.

Some ideas?

Comment: Your code isn't runnable at all, what is your expected output here?

Comment: Yes, I know. I didn´t want to add more noise to the question. I am going to make it runnable for you in a few minutes

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ it runs now. My apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your input and your expected output (three time the same couple of values in your list for each key?), at least you can replace your `for p in plots` by:

```
for p in plots:
    # Select the data you want
    df = bigger_df.filter([p['x'], p['y'], 'S', 'F', 'C'])        # selects the minimum of columns needed
    df = df[df['F'].isin([2, 3, 4, 9]) & df[p['x']].notnull() & df[p['y']].notnull() & (df.S == 123)]   # I have used 123 to simplify, actually the value is an integer variable
    df.sort_values(['C'], ascending=[True], inplace=True)
    # fill the dictionary
    d['xs{}'.format(n)] = [list(df[p['x']]) for x in range(N)]
    d['ys{}'.format(n)] = [list(df[p['y']]) for x in range(N)]
    n += 1
```

At least you save the `for index in range(3)` and doing the same operation on your `bigger_df` 3 times. With `timeit` I dropped from 210 ms with your code to 70.5 ms (around a third) with this one.

**EDIT**: with the way you redefine your question, I think this might do the job you want:

```
# put this code after the definition of plots
s_list = [123, 145, 35]
# create an empty DF to add your results in the loop
df_output = pd.DataFrame(index=s_list, columns=['xs0','ys0', 'xs1', 'ys1', 'xs2', 'ys2']) 
n = 0
for p in plots:
    # Select the data you want and sort them on the same line
    df_p = bigger_df[bigger_df['F'].isin([2, 3, 4, 9]) & bigger_df[p['x']].notnull() & bigger_df[p['y']].notnull() & bigger_df['S'].isin(s_list)].sort_values(['C'], ascending=[True])
    # on bigger df I would do a bit differently if the isin on F and S are the same for the three plots, 
    # I would create a df_select_FS outside of the loop before (might be faster)

    #  Now, you can do groupby on S and then you create a list of element in column p['x'] (and same for p['y'])
    # and you add them in you empty df_output in the right column
    df_output['xs{}'.format(n)] = df_p.groupby('S').apply(lambda x: list(x[p['x']]))
    df_output['ys{}'.format(n)] = df_p.groupby('S').apply(lambda x: list(x[p['y']]))
    n += 1
```

Two notes: first if in your `s_list` you have twice the same value, it might not work the way you want, second where the condition are not meet (like in your example 145 in `S`) then you have `nan` in your `df_output`

Comment: As I write in the comment "I have used the literal 123 to simplify the example". The truth is that I use a variable in the real application, so the result lists are never going to be repeated, I will modify my expected output in my question to avoid the confusion. Thanks for your point.

Comment: just to be sure, it means that your `123` value will be different depending on your `index` value? you'll get it from something like a `list_var` and then using `list_var[index]`?

Comment: Yes @ben, something like that. I can add it to the example thanks, that's a better approach

Comment: Maybe you can use the condition like `df.S.isin(s_list)`in my answer and see how behave df, then use `groupby` on S values. Not sure I'm clear, I'll give a try when I can!

Comment: @ChesuCR see my edit if I understood your problem well

Comment: Yes indeed, "F and S are the same for the three plots". So I have applied all your recommendations and the time fell down from 150-170ms to 50-70ms. Almost 3 times faster!! I appreciate your answer and your effort :)

Comment: That's faster, hope it is good enough. Also, if you want to remove all `nan` by empty list, you can do `df_output[df_output.isnull()] = df_output[df_output.isnull()].applymap(lambda x: [])`

Comment: Thanks!! Good tip, I have tried with [`df.fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) but it did not work.