# Updating multiple line plots dynamically in callback in bokeh

Tags: python-3.x, plot, callback, bokeh, multiline

I have a use case where I have multiple line plots (with legends), and I need to update the line plots based on a column condition. Below is an example of two data set, based on the country, the column data source changes. But the issue I am facing is, the number of columns is not fixed for the data source, and even the types can vary. So, when I update the data source based on a callback when there is a new country selected, I get this error:

```
Error: attempted to retrieve property array for nonexistent field 'pay_conv_7d.content'.
```

I am guessing because in the new data source, the `pay_conv_7d.content` column doesn't exist, but in my plot those lines were already there. I have been trying to fix this issue by various means (making common columns for all country selection - adding the missing column in the data source in callback, but still get issues.

Is there any clean way to have multiple line plots updating using callback, and not do a lot of hackish way? Any insights or help would be really appreciated. Thanks much in advance! :)

```
def setup_multiline_plots(x_axis, y_axis, title_text, data_source, plot):
    num_categories = len(data_source.data['categories'])
    legends_list = list(data_source.data['categories'])
    colors_list = Spectral11[0:num_categories]
    # xs = [data_source.data['%s.'%x_axis].values] * num_categories
    # ys = [data_source.data[('%s.%s')%(y_axis,column)] for column in data_source.data['categories']]
    # data_source.data['x_series'] = xs
    # data_source.data['y_series'] = ys
    # plot.multi_line('x_series', 'y_series', line_color=colors_list,legend='categories', line_width=3, source=data_source)
    plot_list = []
    for (colr, leg, column) in zip(colors_list, legends_list, data_source.data['categories']):
        xs, ys = '%s.'%x_axis, ('%s.%s')%(y_axis,column)
        plot.line(xs,ys, source=data_source, color=colr, legend=leg, line_width=3, name=ys)
        plot_list.append(ys)
    data_source.data['plot_names'] = data_source.data.get('plot_names',[]) + plot_list
    plot.title.text = title_text

def update_plot(country, timeseries_df, timeseries_source,
                aggregate_df, aggregate_source, category,
                plot_pay_7d, plot_r_pay_90d):

    aggregate_metrics = aggregate_df.loc[aggregate_df.country == country]
    aggregate_metrics = aggregate_metrics.nlargest(10, 'cost')
    category_types = list(aggregate_metrics[category].unique())
    timeseries_df = timeseries_df[timeseries_df[category].isin(category_types)]
    timeseries_multi_line_metrics = get_multiline_column_datasource(timeseries_df, category, country)

    # len_series = len(timeseries_multi_line_metrics.data['time.'])
    # previous_legends = timeseries_source.data['plot_names']
    # current_legends = timeseries_multi_line_metrics.data.keys()
    # common_legends = list(set(previous_legends) & set(current_legends))
    # additional_legends_list = list(set(previous_legends) - set(current_legends))
    # for legend in additional_legends_list:
    #     zeros = pd.Series(np.array([0] * len_series), name=legend)
    #     timeseries_multi_line_metrics.add(zeros, legend)
    # timeseries_multi_line_metrics.data['plot_names'] = previous_legends

    timeseries_source.data = timeseries_multi_line_metrics.data
    aggregate_source.data = aggregate_source.from_df(aggregate_metrics)

def get_multiline_column_datasource(df, category, country):

    df_country = df[df.country == country]
    df_pivoted = pd.DataFrame(df_country.pivot_table(index='time', columns=category, aggfunc=np.sum).reset_index())
    df_pivoted.columns = df_pivoted.columns.to_series().str.join('.')
    categories = list(set([column.split('.')[1] for column in list(df_pivoted.columns)]))[1:]
    data_source = ColumnDataSource(df_pivoted)
    data_source.data['categories'] = categories
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had to update data on a `Multiline` glyph. Check [**my question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50008122/how-to-build-a-pandas-dataframe-or-dict-in-an-efficient-way-by-selecting-some) if you want to take a look at my algorithm.

I think you can update a `ColumnDataSource` in three ways at least:

1. You can create a dataframe to instantiate a new CDS

   ```
   cds = ColumnDataSource(df_pivoted)
   data_source.data = cds.data
   ```
2. You can create a dictionary and assign it to the data attribute directly

   ```
   d = {
       'xs0': [[7.0, 986.0], [17.0, 6.0], [7.0, 67.0]],
       'ys0': [[79.0, 69.0], [179.0, 169.0], [729.0, 69.0]],
       'xs1': [[17.0, 166.0], [17.0, 116.0], [17.0, 126.0]],
       'ys1': [[179.0, 169.0], [179.0, 1169.0], [1729.0, 169.0]],
       'xs2': [[27.0, 276.0], [27.0, 216.0], [27.0, 226.0]],
       'ys2': [[279.0, 269.0], [279.0, 2619.0], [2579.0, 2569.0]]
   }
   data_source.data = d
   ```

   Here if you need different sizes of columns or empty columns you can fill the gaps with `NaN` values in order to keep column sizes. And I think this is the solution to your question:

   ```
   import numpy as np
   d = {
       'xs0': [[7.0, 986.0], [17.0, 6.0], [7.0, 67.0]],
       'ys0': [[79.0, 69.0], [179.0, 169.0], [729.0, 69.0]],
       'xs1': [[17.0, 166.0], [np.nan], [np.nan]],
       'ys1': [[179.0, 169.0], [np.nan], [np.nan]],
       'xs2': [[np.nan], [np.nan], [np.nan]],
       'ys2': [[np.nan], [np.nan], [np.nan]]
   }
   data_source.data = d
   ```
3. Or if you only need to modify a few values then you can use the method `patch`. Check the documentation [**here**](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/sources.html#bokeh.models.sources.ColumnDataSource.patch).

   > The following example shows how to patch entire column elements. In this case,

   ```
       source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(foo=[10, 20, 30], bar=[100, 200, 300]))
       patches = {
           'foo' : [ (slice(2), [11, 12]) ],
           'bar' : [ (0, 101), (2, 301) ],
       }
       source.patch(patches)
   ```

   > After this operation, the value of the source.data will be:

   ```
       dict(foo=[11, 22, 30], bar=[101, 200, 301])
   ```

**NOTE**: It is important to make the update in one go to avoid performance issues