# How to call a JS function or Python method when a glyph is completely rendered?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, performance, bokeh

I am using bokeh as a Server Application. When I make a selection in a plot I do some actions in python and I update some sources (CDS). This changes are reflected in the plot. Is there a way to check when the glyphs are completely rendered (after the update)? I want to call a JavaScript function when all is completely loaded? With that function I want to call other python method to update the CDS again.

If I do not wait for this profiles to be rendered probably the application breaks, and that´s what I want to avoid. Actually I did some tests in the past and I had to create a huge CDS instead of several smaller CDS to make it work properly.

### My Use Case. Why do I want to make this?

I have many tabs in my layout, they can be 10 for example. And each tab has some plots (3-6 plots). If I update the entire ColumnDataSource at the same time, it will take a while. Then I want to make it more fluent, so I would like to update only the data of the current visible tab, it will render faster and the user would receive an immediate response. I can disable the rest of the tabs temporarily to prevent malfunctions. At this moment I would need to call the JS or python method in order to update the content of the rest of the tabs.

Here a drawing of what I want to achieve in order to speed up the process:

[image: drawing_steps]

#### About the data

Basically I have two DataFrames, one to build the cloud of points (around 5000 row and 130 columns) and I extract from the selected points another DataFrame to know which lines I should draw (360 columns and 5 to 15 rows), making some filters and selections. The algorythm I have used is in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50025959/4891717) of a question I have written time ago. With this amount of data the algorythm takes 6 or 7 seconds to finish.

Any other idea of how to improve the performance or how to split or the computing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time ago I made a trick to check if my design would work if I could trigger some function if the plots were rendered:

1. First I updated the current tab. This worked very well and fast.
2. Then I set a timeout to update the data of the rest of the tabs. But, in the meantime this second algorythm was being executed I could not work with the plots of the current tab because they were frozen.

So, the approach of triggering a function when everything is rendered is not a good idea, because even with such a callback the app would not work as I was expecting.

Answer (score 1):

To improve the rendering speed you could try the `webgl JavaScript API`. This Bokeh documentation page [Speeding up with WebGL](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/webgl.html) explains how to do it.  `webgl` supports circles, lines and most of the markers. Application:

```
p = Plot(output_backend="webgl")  # for the glyph API
p = figure(output_backend="webgl")  # for the plotting API
```

Please be aware that users report issues with `webgl` like plot stuttering, etc... but it may work in your case depend on which type of glyphs your plot contains.

Also make sure your data passed to the plot doesn't include NaN's as it is known to slow down Bokeh performance.

**To my knowledge there is no attribute that indicates that rendering is completed or is still ongoing** but you may think about some other alternatives to speed things up like combination of Bokeh with [Datashader](http://datashader.org/) (pre-rendering large datasets into a fixed-size raster image) or [Dask](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html) (speed up data reading from multiple sources like multiple csv files)

> For example you could have one standard Bokeh plot where you make a
>   selection and let the other plots being generated as Datashader images
>   and embed them in Bokeh plots.

[This example](https://github.com/pyviz/datashader) shows how to combine Bokeh + Datashader which significantly improves performance especially when over-plotting takes place. Please note that each time a single point is added to the plot entire canvas area will be re-drawn in the browser. This is how browsers work. Datashader can provide a single image so updating the plot is much quicker while you can still use Toolbar tools like zoom, pan etc....

Also the Python code implementation details counts. Using e.g. gridplot to link many plots can slow down performance so it is better to add them one by one to the document root, etc...

Comment: Thank you for devoting your time writing a response. I have enabled `webgl` from the begining, that is OK. I am not sure if I can use Datashader because I should be able to use the selecting tools all the time, not just panning and zoomming tools. I did not know about the Dask DataFrame, I have updated my answer with more details, do you think that this kind of DataFrame will speed up the computing of the algorythm with the data size I am working with?

Comment: According to documentation Dask comes handy in the following situations: 1) Manipulating large datasets, even when those datasets don’t fit in memory. 
2) Accelerating long computations by using many cores. 
3) Distributed computing on large datasets with standard Pandas operations like groupby, join, and time series computations.

Comment: Thanks for your possible solutions, but none of them helped me. `webgl` was already enabled. I cannot use a `datashader` because I need to keep interaction with the samples. I tried with a Dask Dataframe as well, but the algorythm took even longer to finish (due to the overhead, I think). Anyway I will upvote your answer because they may work for other people !